# How do you open a terminal?

Tags: dual-boot

I was given the advice to open a terminal & type in some commands to try & repair my computer but don't know what a terminal is.Can someone explain please?

Comment: go [through Using The Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

Comment: What's wrong with the word "and"?

Comment: It's long winded & has unnecessary letters :-)

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, which is the keyboard shortcut for most(all?) Ubuntu versions.

Alternately, you can go to Dash and search for "Terminal".

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `gnome-terminal` will also open one.

Comment: FWIW it's not the shortcut for Kubuntu.

Comment: I managed to open the terminal & type the advice I have been given in another question but then it asks for my password but won't let me type it!

Comment: it is security reason. Just type your password and press Enter

Comment: How does it "won't let you type it!"? Normally, the there is nothing shown while you type the password. Not even dots or so. That makes it much harder to guess parts of your password when looking. When dots are shown, anybody could see if you have a short password, and know it's easy to hack, for example.

Comment: @user266597 Check tgm4883 ' s answer in this question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/132939/i-cannot-enter-my-password-when-using-sudo-to-install-sophos-av-for-linux . sudo doesn't display your password, which doesn't mean it is not recording it. just type it and press enter. FYI I think you can use backspace if you make a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your advice gents (& ladies if there are any among your persona’s...).Good sound & easy to follow.